# Laravel 4 file download throws error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I want to download files and keep track of download count so i have made a url to retrieve it, but I have a problem with `Response::download()`.

```
Response::download($url, 200, array('content-type' => 'application/octet-stream'));
```

This always says that file does not exists. Since it prints out file url in error report, I have copied that url into browser and file is there. 
Why won't it download file.

I have `Route::get('getfile', 'somecontroller@getfile')` and this `getfile` function receives file ID as a parameter.

Any ideas?

Comment: can u show us the `$url`?

Comment: it's a path to file relative to site root. eg `/downloads/files/file.zip`

Comment: @VukBG try it like `./downloads/files/file.zip`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you should use the absolute path for your file (not relative).
If your files are stored within storage directory (app/storage) then you can use storage_path() helper method and concatenate it with your $url var.

Comment: it's not in storage. It's in public_html. I'll give it a go